# Cocos2D-JS Can not simulate Physics

Tags: javascript, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-js

I am trying to simulate physics in Cocos2D-JS but I do not succeed. I am new to Cocos2D-JS. Can someone tell me why my Sprites are not falling if I have the world set with gravity to True? and also why does the DistanceJoint not work? Thank you very much.

```js
var b2Vec2 = Box2D.Common.Math.b2Vec2
    , b2AABB = Box2D.Collision.b2AABB
    , b2BodyDef = Box2D.Dynamics.b2BodyDef
    , b2Body = Box2D.Dynamics.b2Body
    , b2FixtureDef = Box2D.Dynamics.b2FixtureDef
    , b2Fixture = Box2D.Dynamics.b2Fixture
    , b2World = Box2D.Dynamics.b2World
    , b2PolygonShape = Box2D.Collision.Shapes.b2PolygonShape
    , b2CircleShape = Box2D.Collision.Shapes.b2CircleShape
    , b2DebugDraw = Box2D.Dynamics.b2DebugDraw
    , b2MouseJointDef =  Box2D.Dynamics.Joints.b2MouseJointDef
    , b2DistanceJointDef =  Box2D.Dynamics.Joints.b2DistanceJointDef
    , b2Shape = Box2D.Collision.Shapes.b2Shape
    , b2_dynamicBody =  Box2D.Dynamics.b2_dynamicBody

var HelloWorldLayer = cc.Layer.extend({
    spriteSoccerball:null,
    spriteBasketball:null,
    ctor:function () {
        this._super();
        var size = cc.winSize;
        var gravity = new Box2D.Common.Math.b2Vec2(0, -10)
        world = new b2World(gravity,true);
        //--------------------------
        var helloLabel = new cc.LabelTTF("RoboArm", "Arial", 38);
        helloLabel.x = size.width / 2;
        helloLabel.y = size.height / 2 + 200;
        this.addChild(helloLabel, 5);
        //--------------------------
        spriteSoccerball = new cc.Sprite(res.soccerBall_png);
        spriteSoccerball.setPositionX(300);
        spriteSoccerball.setPositionY(300);
        spriteSoccerball.anchorX=0.5;
        spriteSoccerball.anchorY=0.5;
        spriteSoccerball.setScale(0.1, 0.1);
        this.addChild(spriteSoccerball, 0);
        //--------------------------
        spriteBasketball = new cc.Sprite(res.basketBall_png);
        spriteBasketball.setPositionX(200);
        spriteBasketball.setPositionY(200);
        spriteBasketball.anchorX=0.5;
        spriteBasketball.anchorY=0.5;
        spriteBasketball.setScale(0.1, 0.1);
        this.addChild(spriteBasketball, 0);
        //--------------------------
        a = createBody(world, spriteBasketball, spriteBasketball.getPositionX(), spriteBasketball.getPositionY(), 1, 1);
        b = createBody(world, spriteSoccerball, spriteSoccerball.getPositionX(), spriteSoccerball.getPositionY(), 1, 1);
        createDistanceJoint(world,a,b);
        //--------------------------
        var listener = cc.EventListener.create({
            event: cc.EventListener.TOUCH_ALL_AT_ONCE,
            onTouchBegan: function (touch, event) {
                return true;
            },
            onTouchesMoved: function (touch, event) {
                var pos = touch[0].getLocation();
                a.SetPosition(pos);
                return true;
            },
            onTouchEnded: function (touch, event) {
                return true;
            }
        });
        cc.eventManager.addListener(listener, this);
        this.scheduleUpdate();
    },
    update: function (dt) {
        spriteBasketball.setPosition(a.GetPosition().x ,
            a.GetPosition().y);
        var timeStep = 1.0/(fps * 0.8);
        //move the box2d world ahead
        world.Step(timeStep , 8 , 3);
        world.ClearForces();
        //call this function again after 1/60 seconds or 16.7ms
        setTimeout(this.step , 1000 / fps);
    }
});

//Create standard boxes of given height , width at x,y
function createBox(world, x, y, width, height, options)
{
    var body_def = new b2BodyDef();
    var fix_def = new b2FixtureDef();

    fix_def.shape = new b2PolygonShape();
    fix_def.shape.SetAsBox( width/2 , height/2 );

    body_def.position.Set(x , y);
    body_def.linearDamping = 0.5;
    body_def.angularDamping = 0.5;

    var b = world.CreateBody( body_def );
    var f = b.CreateFixture(fix_def);

    return b;
}

//Create standard boxes of given height , width at x,y
function createBody(world, sprite, x, y, width, height)
{
    var body_def = new b2BodyDef;
    body_def.type = b2_dynamicBody;
    body_def.angle = 1;
    body_def.gravityScale = 1.0;
    body_def.position.Set(x, y);
    body_def.linearVelocity.Set(1,1);
    body_def.angularVelocity = 2.0;
    body_def.linearDamping = 3.0;
    body_def.angularDamping = 4.0;
    body_def.inertiaScale = 3.0;
    body_def.active=true;

    var fix_def = new b2FixtureDef;
    fix_def.shape = new b2PolygonShape();
    fix_def.shape.SetAsBox( width/2 , height/2 );
    fix_def.density = 1.0;
    fix_def.friction = 0.3;

    var b = world.CreateBody(body_def);
    b.CreateFixture(fix_def);

    return b;
}

function createDistanceJoint(world, a,b)
{
    //create distance joint between b and c
    var joint_def = new b2DistanceJointDef;
    joint_def.bodyA = a;
    joint_def.bodyB = b;

    //connect the centers - center in local coordinate - relative to body is 0,0
    joint_def.localAnchorA = new b2Vec2(0.5,0.5);
    joint_def.localAnchorB = new b2Vec2(0.5,0.5);

    //difference in angle of each body
    joint_def.referenceAngle = 1 * Math.PI / 3;

    //add the joint to the world
    world.CreateJoint(joint_def);
}

var HelloWorldScene = cc.Scene.extend({
    onEnter:function () {
        this._super();
        var layer = new HelloWorldLayer();
        this.addChild(layer);
    }
});
```

Comment: Your posted snippet shows the error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: Box2D is not defined` is the case in your code as well?

Comment: I am sorry but I do not know what you mean, I do not receive any error in Chrome in Developer Tools just some warnings.

Comment: Click the 'Run code snippet' button and then look at the displayed panel, at the bottom of that panel it shows the console output which, in this case, displays the message I pasted in the previous comment. If that doesn't happen in your own code there's something missing from your "*[mcve]*" code.

Comment: If there is a linking issue, do you know how to enable Box2D in Cocos2D-X JS ?:)

Comment: I'm afraid not; I can help with some general JavaScript problems but I'm not familiar with this particular library.

Comment: As long as the bodyDef stores information it means it can read the library, however the Physics just do not work and I can not figure out why :(